# What's self-consistent matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm reading a paper and it mentioned the following: "one obtains this self-consistent matrix formulation:" and then they mentioned a formulation. But I couldn't understand the meaning of a self-consistent matrix.

Comment: Are you sure it's not intended to be read "self-consistent (matrix formulation)"?

Comment: @Rebecca "one obtains a self-consistent matrix formulation"

Comment: I mean as in the "matrix formulation" is self-consistent (not the matrix).  In any case, it'd be easier to diagnose if we knew the paper and what the formulation actually is.

Comment: @Rebecca http://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.0725.pdf page 11, formula (14)

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, it's the "matrix formulation" that's self-consistent, i.e., the formula used to define the similarity index $S$ discussed in the paper.

The reason this is noted is that $S$ is defined in terms of $S$ itself, so it's not immediate that it's even well-defined.

The manipulations in (14) show that it can be equivalently defined non-recursively, and thus is indeed well-defined.